# What does the Parameter superb in LAPACKE_dgesvd(..) mean?

Tags: c, lapack

Putting up questions like this one raises a bad conscience... nevertheless I find it surprisingly difficult to google this one. I am experimenting with

```
lapack_int LAPACKE_dgesvd(
  int matrix_order, char jobu, char jobvt,
  lapack_int m, lapack_int n, double* a,
  lapack_int lda, double* s, double* u, lapack_int ldu,
  double* vt, lapack_int ldvt, double* superb);
```

which promises a Singular Value Decomposition. Having already stopped to fear Fortran I found a gold mine of information here: http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/double/dgesvd.f

Actually that link's target explains all parameters but the LAPACKE specific **double* superb** (well and the order parameter, but in FORTRAN all is COL_MAJOR).

Next, here http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/lapacke_dgesvd_row.c.htm I found a program which seems to hint at 'this is some kind of worker cache'.

However, if that were true what is the reason for **LAPACKE_dgesvd_work(..)**?

In addition I have a second question: In the example they use *min(M,N)-1* as a size for superb. Why?

Comment: Looking at the sources here: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/dee/lapacke__dgesvd_8c_source.html it just seems to be some sort of backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/double/dgesvd.f , about parameter `WORK` of the fortran version :

WORK    (workspace/output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (MAX(1,LWORK))
         On exit, if INFO = 0, WORK(1) returns the optimal LWORK; if INFO > 0, WORK(2:MIN(M,N)) contains the unconverged superdiagonal elements of an upper bidiagonal matrix B whose diagonal is in S (not necessarily sorted). B satisfies A = U * B * VT, so it has the same singular values as A, and singular vectors related by U and VT.

There is a chance that superb is the superdiagonal of this upper bidiagonal matrix `B` which has the same singular values as A. This also explain the length `min(n,m)-1`

A look at lapack-3.5.0/lapacke/src/lapacke_dgesvd.c downloaded from http://www.netlib.org/lapack/ confirms it.

The source code also shows that the high level function `lapacke_dgesvd()` calls the middle level interface `lapacke_dgesvd_work()`. If you use the high level interface, you don't have to care about the optimal size of `WORK`. It will be computed and `WORK` will be allocated in `lapacke_dgesvd()`

I wonder if there is any gain to use the middle level interface instead...Maybe when this function is called many times on little matrices of same sizes...

Bye,

Francis

Comment: Ic. As you said, the source you hinted at (lapacke_dgesvd.c) contains the line "for( i=0; i<MIN(m,n)-1; i++ ) { superb[i] = work[i+1]; }" as only reference to superb. So it _is_ in fact connected to work and the size min(m,n)-1 does in fact suffice (knowledge that effectively solves my problem). Nevertheless, highlevel or not, this "superb" is a necessary parameter and I feel a bit more confident about it now. Thanks a lot!